# Computing the expectation of $e^\lambda x$ for $\lambda >0$ and $x$ a standard Gaussian random variable

Tags: real-analysis, probability

in my lecture we have the following statement:

Denote by $x$ a standard Gaussian random variable and let $\lambda > 0$. Hence $\mathbb{E} [e^{\lambda x}]$ is $e^{\lambda^2/2}$.

I wanted to repeat the calculation behind this statement, but I am always ending up with the value 0 instead of $e^{\lambda^2/2}$.

In my understanding a standard Gaussian random variable has a density function of $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$. In order to evaluate $\mathbb{E}[e^{\lambda x}]$ I compute:

$\mathbb{E}[e^{\lambda x}]=\int_{- \infty}^{\infty} e^{\lambda x} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{\lambda^2/2} erf(\frac{x-\lambda}{2}) |_{-\infty}^{\infty}=0$ where $erf$ denotes the error function. (https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erf.html).

May someone please explain, where I am going wrong?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you have is in the very last step. You write that
$$\operatorname{Erf}\Big(\frac{x-\lambda}{2}\Big) \Big|_{-\infty}^\infty = 0$$
while this is equal to $2$. Indeed,
$$
\lim_{u\to-\infty}\operatorname{Erf}(u)=-1, \qquad \lim_{u\to\infty}\operatorname{Erf}(u)=1
$$

Comment: Thank you! Of course, I did not see that.

Comment: Glad this helped! @samabu

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact that $-\tfrac{x^2}{2}+\lambda x=-\tfrac{(x-\lambda)^2}{2}+\tfrac{\lambda^2}{2}$ to get an integral of $\exp{\lambda^2}{2}$ times the integral $\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty$ over the density of a normal random variable with mean $\lambda$ (which is 1).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. With this I get: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{\frac{\lambda^2}{2}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{(x-\lambda)^2}{2}} dx$. But then I get the same equation is before.